Runtime file or assembly not found exception on docker container
I have an api I run it locally without problem. But when I run it docker container I receive this error on runtime
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols, Version=7.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified."

And here is my built in version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols version .

Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env

WORKDIR /App

EXPOSE 7070
# Copy everything
COPY . /App
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0

WORKDIR /App

COPY --from=build-env /App/out .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:7070

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ReservoireApi.dll"]

I check previous aswers but none of them solved my issue .
I tried to check assembly references and all nuget packages are using same version .
What am I missing I could not find out so far .
I can send a request but it breaks the application and I receive http 500 response .

What SDK version so you have locally? What happens when you run dotnet --list-sdks?

dotnet 8.0.205 ,dotnet  5.0.202 and dotnet  5.0.201 @VladDX

Separate idea: you can try to reference the package explicitly.

It comes with dotnet 8 which package embedded in the dotnet sdk , I can not reference it . If there is a way Id like to try

You definitely should be able to explicitly reference it. It's a public NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols/

The -o out keyword creates problem . This -o out keyword buggy it forces irrelevant packages dlls in publish files so application does not work .
I just use
dotnet publish -c release 
instead of
dotnet publish -c release -o out => bugged
And I found published folder path then modified the relevant docker line fixed my issue
COPY --from=build-env /app/ReservoireApi/bin/Release/net8.0/publish .
